# Dijkstra's Shortest Path Implemented with Min Heap

Tags: c++, graph, nodes, dijkstra, vertices

I am trying to implement Dijksta's shortest path using a min heap, but I am having issues with the distance field not updating correctly after performing relaxation. I also get segmentation fault when trying some test cases and I am not sure why. On pressing R,the program should read in a graph, and build the edge adjacency list of the graph. The edge adjacency list is an array (indexed by the vertices) of singularly linked lists, where the list according to a node v denotes the outgoing neighbors of node v.This is built using the graphinput.txt and the buildGraph function I outline at the bottom; The input text file is the following where 25 and 50 are the number of vertices and edges respectively:

```
25 50
1 1 3
1 6 2
1 2 7
1 11 1
6 11 3
11 6 2
7 1 4
11 12 4
2 7 10
7 2 10
16 12 7
21 16 4
21 22 1
22 21 2
3 1 5
18 21 1
18 22 3
22 23 5
12 18 8
18 12 7
7 13 3
12 8 2
2 8 1
2 9 3
4 3 4
5 4 7
10 5 3
4 10 10
14 4 15
15 10 8
10 15 6
10 15 7
8 13 2
8 9 1
9 9 4
13 18 1
23 23 7
23 24 4
23 14 1
24 13 9
14 19 1
19 24 1
15 14 2
14 20 16
14 25 30
20 25 15
24 25 26
23 25 8
25 15 2
17 16 13
```

On reading F S T 1, the program is to print the length of the shortest path from node s to node t.
On reading F S T 0, the program is to output the shortest path from node s to node t.
If the nodes are not reachable it is to output an error.
Here are the structs I am using where d in ELEMENT is the distance, p is the parent and key is the value. In heap, H is an array of type ELEMENT with index ranging from 0 to capacity
These are my heap structs:

```
struct ELEMENT{ //declaring the element struct with a key
    int key;
    int d;
    int p;
};

struct HEAP{ //declaring the heap struct with a capacity size and a pointer h
    int capacity;
    int size;
    ELEMENT *h;
};
```

My graph structs:

```
struct GRAPH{
    int v;
    int e;
    struct ELEMENT *h;
    struct LIST** A;
};

struct LIST{
    int neighbor;
    int weight;
    struct LIST* next;
};
```

I then use the following heap functions:

```
ELEMENT deleteMin(GRAPH *g){
    ELEMENT trueMin;
    if(g->v >=1){   //proceeds only if the heap size is greater than or equal to 1
        trueMin = g->h[1]; //initializing element variable for the min that gets deleted
    }
    if(g->v < 1){ //if the heap is empty print this error
        cout << "Error: heap empty" << endl;
    }
    else{
        ELEMENT min = g->h[1];
        g->h[1] = g->h[g->v];
        g->v--;
        minHeapify(g,g->h[1].key);
        trueMin = min; //else min is equal to first element, is swapped with the last, size is decreased, and minheapfiy is called
    }
    return trueMin;
}

void decreaseKey(GRAPH *g, int index, int value){
    if(index > g->v || index < 1){ //if the index is greater than the size of the index is less than 1 print error

        //cout<< "Error: invalid index" << endl;
        return;
     }

    if(value > g->h[index].d){// if the value trying to be increased is greater than the current index value print error
        //cout << "Error: new key is bigger than current key" << endl;
        return;
    }
    else{
        g->h[index].d = value; //else set the index equal to the key value and swap the parent until the parent has a less value
        while( index > 1 && g->h[parent(index)].d > g->h[index].d){
            swap(&g->h[index], &g->h[parent(index)]);
            index =  parent(index);

        }
    }

}

void minHeapify(GRAPH *g, int i){ //minHeapify algorithm to maintain min heap property where the parent of any given node is always less than its children
    int smallest = 0;
    int l = left(i);
    int r = right(i);
    if(l <= g->v && g->h[l].d < g->h[i].d){ //checking if children exist
        smallest = l;//setting the smallest equal to left if the left is smaller
    } else{
        smallest = i;
    }
    if(r <= g->v && g->h[r].d < g->h[smallest].d){ //checking if children exist
        smallest = r;//setting the smallest equal to right if the right is smaller
    }
    if(smallest != i){ //if the smallest is not equal to i entered by user then swap and minHeapify function
        int temp = g->h[i].d;
        int temp1 = g->h[i].key;
        int temp2 = g->h[i].p;
        g->h[i].key = g->h[smallest].key;
        g->h[i].d = g->h[smallest].d;
        g->h[i].p = g->h[smallest].p;
        g->h[smallest].key = temp;
        g->h[smallest].d = temp1;
        g->h[smallest].p = temp2;
        minHeapify(g, smallest);

    }
}

void buildHeap(GRAPH *g){

    for(int i = floor(g->v/2); i >= 1; i--){
        minHeapify(g, i); //performing the buildHeap operation
    }

}

int parent(int i){
    return floor(i/2);//parent function to return parent node
}
int left(int i){//left function to return left node
    return 2 * i;
}
int right(int i){//right function to return right node
    return (2 * i + 1);
}
void swap(ELEMENT *a, ELEMENT *b){ //swaps elements using pointers and a temp variable
    ELEMENT temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
    return;
}
```

For my graph, I use the following functions:

```
GRAPH* initializeGraph(){ //initializing the graph
    GRAPH *g = new GRAPH;
    g->v=0;
    g->h=nullptr;
    g->A=nullptr;
    g->e=0;
    return g;
}

void initializeSingleSource(GRAPH *g, int s)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= g->v; i++)
    {
        g->h[i].d = INT_MAX - 1000; //setting all the distances to infinity
        g->h[i].p = -1; //setting parent field to nonexistent

    }
    g->h[s].d = 0; //setting the source distance to 0 to start the algorithm
    //g->h = new ELEMENT[g->v + 1];
}

void relax(GRAPH *g, int u, int v, int w)
{
    int uindex = 0; //variables to search for the index of u and v
    int vindex = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i <= g->v; i++){ //searching
        if(g->h[i].key == u){
            uindex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <= g->v; i++){ //searching
        if(g->h[i].key == v){
            vindex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (g->h[vindex].d > g->h[uindex].d + w) //performing relaxation on indices 
    {
        g->h[vindex].d = g->h[uindex].d + w;
        g->h[vindex].p = u;
        decreaseKey(g, g->h[vindex].d, w + g->h[uindex].d); //calling decreasekey to maintain minheap property
    }
}

void Dijkstra(GRAPH *g, int s, int t, int flag) //s and t are source and target nodes flag determines what to print
{
    g->h = new ELEMENT[g->v + 1];
    for (int i = 1; i <= g->v; i++) { //setting i 
     g->h[i].key = i;
}
    initializeSingleSource(g,s); //setting initial fields
    std::vector<ELEMENT> S; //vector to hold extracted min elements
    buildHeap(g); //calling buildheap on g
    //cout << g->h[s].d << endl;
    while (g->v > 0)
    {

        ELEMENT u = deleteMin(g); //extracting min
        S.push_back(u);
        LIST *temp = g->A[u.key]; //pointer for adjacency list
        while(temp){
            relax(g, u.key,temp->neighbor,temp->weight); //performing relaxation
                cout << "update " << temp->neighbor << " distance to " << g->h[temp->neighbor].d << endl; //for debugging purposes
                temp =  temp->next;
        }

    }
    for(int i = 0; i < S.size(); i++){
        if(S[i].key == t){
            if(S[i].d == INT_MAX - 1000){ //if distance is still infinity after relaxation then error
                std::cout << "Error: node " << t << " not reachable from " << s << std::endl;
            }
            else{
                if(flag == 1){  //if flag is 1 then output the length of the shortest path
                    std::cout << "LENGTH: " << S[i].d << std::endl;
                }
               // if (flag == 0 && s == t){
                 //   cout << "PATH: " << s << endl; //wrote this to get more test cases passing without solving real problem
                //}
                else if(flag == 0){ //if 0 output the path for shortest distance
                    vector<int> path;
                    int temp = t;
                    while(temp != -1){ //while temp os not -1 loop through vector 
                        for(int i = 0; i < S.size(); i++){
                            if(S[i].key == temp){
                                path.insert(path.begin(), temp); //insert path until -1
                                temp = S[i].p;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    std::cout << "PATH: ";
                    for(int i = 0; i < S.size(); i++){
                        std::cout << path[i]; //printing path as comma separated list
                        if(i < path.size() - 1){
                            std::cout << ", ";
                        }
                    }
                    std::cout << std::endl; 
                }
            }

        }
    }
    delete g->h;   
}

void buildGraph(GRAPH *g)
{

    //GRAPH *g = new GRAPH;
    ifstream myfile("Ginput.txt"); //building the adjacency list
    int v1 = 0, e1 = 0;
    myfile >> v1 >> e1;
    if (v1 == 0 || e1 == 0){
        std::cout << "Errorr: unable to open file " << std::endl;
    }
    g->v = v1;
    g->e = e1;
    g->h = nullptr;
    g->A = new LIST *[v1 + 1];
    for (int i = 1; i <= v1; i++)
    {
        g->A[i] = NULL;
    }
    int u,v,w;
    while (myfile >> u >> v >> w)
    {
        LIST *temp = new LIST;
        temp->neighbor = v;
        temp->weight = w;
        temp->next = NULL;
        if (g->A[u] == NULL)
        {
            g->A[u] = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->next = g->A[u];
            g->A[u] = temp;
        }
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

And this is an example of the output I get when I print what relax is doing in my while loop of dijkstra function.

```
R
COMMAND: R
F 1 1 1
COMMAND: F 1 1 1
update 11 distance to 32712
update 2 distance to 32718
update 6 distance to 32713
update 1 distance to 2147482647
update 15 distance to 32713
update 25 distance to 2147482647
update 13 distance to 32720
update 25 distance to 2147482647
update 14 distance to 32712
update 24 distance to 2147482647
update 23 distance to 2147482647
update 23 distance to 2147482647
update 21 distance to 2147482647
update 22 distance to 2147482647
update 16 distance to 32715
update 25 distance to 2147482647
update 24 distance to 2147482647
update 12 distance to 32718
update 22 distance to 2147482647
update 21 distance to 2147482647
update 16 distance to 32715
update 12 distance to 32718
update 14 distance to 32712
update 10 distance to 32719
update 25 distance to 2147482647
update 20 distance to 2147482647
update 19 distance to 2147482647
update 4 distance to 32726
update 18 distance to 2147482647
update 8 distance to 32713
update 18 distance to 2147482647
update 12 distance to 32718
update 6 distance to 32713
update 15 distance to 32713
update 15 distance to 32713
update 5 distance to 32714
update 9 distance to 2147482647
update 9 distance to 2147482647
update 13 distance to 32720
update 13 distance to 32720
update 2 distance to 32718
update 1 distance to 32713
update 11 distance to 32712
update 4 distance to 32726
update 10 distance to 32719
update 3 distance to 2147482647
update 1 distance to 32718
update 9 distance to 2147482647
update 8 distance to 32713
update 7 distance to 2147482647
LENGTH: 0
F 6 11 0
COMMAND: F 6 11 0
update 11 distance to 32714
update 15 distance to 32713
update 25 distance to 2147482647
update 13 distance to 32720
update 25 distance to 2147482647
update 14 distance to 32712
update 24 distance to 2147482647
update 23 distance to 2147482647
update 23 distance to 2147482647
update 21 distance to 2147482647
update 22 distance to 2147482647
update 16 distance to 32715
update 25 distance to 2147482647
update 24 distance to 2147482647
update 12 distance to 32718
update 22 distance to 2147482647
update 21 distance to 2147482647
update 16 distance to 32715
update 12 distance to 32718
update 14 distance to 32712
update 10 distance to 32719
update 25 distance to 2147482647
update 20 distance to 2147482647
update 19 distance to 2147482647
update 4 distance to 32726
update 18 distance to 2147482647
update 8 distance to 32713
update 18 distance to 2147482647
update 12 distance to 32718
update 6 distance to 3
update 15 distance to 32713
update 15 distance to 32713
update 5 distance to 32714
update 9 distance to 2147482647
update 9 distance to 2147482647
update 13 distance to 32720
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This is the piece of main where I use Dijkstra function:

```
case 'F':
                printf("COMMAND: %c %d %d %d\n",c ,f, i, v);
                if (!g) {
                    std::cout << "Error: graph not initialized" << std::endl;
                    break;
                }
                if(f > 25 || f < 1 || i > 25 || i < 1){
                    if (v != 0 && v != 1){
                        std::cout << "Error: one or more invalid nodes" << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "Error: invalid flag value" << std::endl;
                        break;
                    }
                } 
                if(f > 25 || f < 1 || i > 25 || i < 1){
                    std::cout << "Error: one or more invalid nodes" << std::endl;
                    break;
                } 
                if (v != 0 && v != 1) {
                    std::cout << "Error: invalid flag value" << std::endl;
                    break;
                }
                Dijkstra(g,f,i,v);
                buildGraph(g); //called to avoid errors when extractmin is called to decrease graph size
             break;
```

If anyone could please tell me what I am doing incorrectly, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: In  "relax" what happens if either of uindex or vindex is zero?

Comment: @Surt Hello. I do not think it is possible for uindex or vindex to be zero because the search starts at index 1.

Comment: they are initialised to zero and if not found they will be zero. But your invariant could guarantee that the search never fails.

Comment: @Surt Should I not be initializing them to 0?

Comment: the posted code is written in C++, and C++ and C are two very different languages (and getting further apart with each new release.  Suggest removing the `c` tag from your question

Comment: Got it. I will update the tags

Comment: @binarycoffee356 I'd suggest that you check that you found something (or not found it) and then handle the condition.